# Java NIO select() returns 0 in Android 4.1.2 when no network (under emulator)

Tags: java, android, nio

I'm trying to use Java NIO. All was ok, until I tried to test connection when emulator has no internet access. And here next results:

At 2.2 select() selects 1 key and after that finishConnect() call throws Exception. As expected. But it working only if first line is uncommented (preferIPv6 = false).

But at 4.1.2 select() always returns zero. And selected keys set is empty. Inspecting values says, that selection key is always not ready for any operations, interestOps is 8 (OP_CONNECT).

In java connect() call throwing IOException: Network is unreachable. As expected.

What I do wrong and how to cause select() to block?

```java
//System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");

try {
    Selector selector = Selector.open();

    SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();

    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    boolean connected = socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("173.194.44.3", 80));

    SelectionKey selectionKey;

    if (connected) {
        selectionKey = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    } else {
        selectionKey = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
    }

    while (true) {
        int selected = selector.select();

        if (selected == 0) continue;

        for (SelectionKey key : selector.selectedKeys()) {
            if (socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
                key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            }
        }

        selector.selectedKeys().clear();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("IOException", e);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `select()` returns zero, something has timed out. You shouldn't just continue, you should treat it as an error or a warning. For example if you were selecting for sixty seconds waiting for `OP_CONNECT` to fire and `select()` returned zero you should treat that as a connect timeout.

Comment: Yes, I have created queue for not connected channels. And if this queue is not empty, I'm doing select(TIMEOUT) instead of just blocking select. Then poll elements from queue while channel connect time is more, than TIMEOUT. And close this channels.

Thanks.

Comment: In my view you should always do a timed `select().` If it happens you can traverse the keyset looking for operations that have timed out: if e.g. you have keys whose only `interestOp` is `OP_CONNECT` you can close it, log it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Problem looks solvable.

I'm added OP_READ interest and somewhy selector selected key, that ready for read.

But when I'm tried to read, NotYetConnectedException throwed. So, I can catch this and handle this. Then, select blocks.

But it looks like bug.

```java
try {
    Selector selector = Selector.open();

    SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();

    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    boolean connected = socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("173.194.44.3", 80));

    SelectionKey selectionKey;

    int validOps = socketChannel.validOps();

    if (connected) {
        selectionKey = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    } else {
        selectionKey = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);

    while (true) {
        int selected = selector.select();

        if (selected == 0) continue;

        for (SelectionKey key : selector.selectedKeys()) {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

            if ((key.interestOps() & SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT) != 0 && key.isConnectable())
            {
                if (socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                }
            }

            if (key.isReadable()) {
                while (true) {
                    int readed = 0;

                    try {
                        readed = sc.read(buffer);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        sc.close();
                    }

                    if (readed == 0) break;

                    if (readed == -1) throw new RuntimeException("Closed");
                }
            }
        }

        selector.selectedKeys().clear();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("IOException", e);
}
```

Maybe here exists more "non-magic" solution?